# Rails 5: Clearance - User CRUD?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clearance

I am currently using https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance
for authentication.

It allows me to sign-up & sign-in using password and email.

But I was wondering how I can configure it to have a CRUD pages for the generated users model, because I actually want to see a list of registered users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular Users controller, subclassed from clearance.

```
class UsersController < Clearance::UsersController
  def index
    @logged_in_users = User.where(blah) #whatever logic you need to retrieve the list of users 
  end
end
```

I created my Users controller first, then ran the clearance generator, and then the routes generator. After generating the default routes, you can modify to point to your own controller.

```
rails g clearance:install
rails g clearance:routes


  resources :users, controller: "users" do
    resource :password,
    controller: "clearance/passwords",
    only: [:create, :edit, :update]
  end

get "/sign_in" => "clearance/sessions#new", as: "sign_in"
delete "/sign_out" => "clearance/sessions#destroy", as: "sign_out"
get "/sign_up" => "clearance/users#new", as: "sign_up"
```